# PhoneGap - Unable to properly connect to the server

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-desktop-app

I am using a virtual window server `IP:192.168.15.113`. Phonegap show my project is connect to http://192.168.15.113:3000. I connect to this ip address to my android phonegap developer app and it keep shows `unable to properly connect to the server.` I am using bridged `adapter` with my host network and try to ping `192.168.15.113` with my android phone. All works fine.

I have no idea why it just couldn't connect. Please help me.

Comment: I solved this problem. Please make sure your firewall setting to allow both inbound and outbound connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an [FAQ](http://docs.phonegap.com/references/developer-app/troubleshoot-faq/) for common networking issues when pairing the PhoneGap Developer App with the PhoneGap Desktop.

You might be able to find the solution to your issue there.